# Fields being tripled in the section details

Tags: crystal-reports, report

My report receives a populated dataset with with only one item in the products list, yet the Crystal report prints 3 items in the product list.

[image]

I tried to remove all fields of the details section, yet the CR prints 3 empty lines.

[image]

This is insane. There are no fields inside the details section, yet CR prints 3 lines. Should I start looking for silver bullets?

**EDIT:** I'm importing the data to a dataset using a xml. There is no database behind and I'm sure that my dataset contains only one product.

Comment: Are you using "select distinct" in the query? Do you have 1-to-many relationships in the query that you aren't displaying in the report?

Comment: Sorry, i forgot to say, I populate the dataset with via xml data.

Comment: May be start on a fresh report. I would do that instead of wasting a lot of time figuring out such random things.

Comment: Oh :( Well, I'll try that...